# .closest().find().text() finding multiple elements inner text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to find the closest `<h4>` to a clicked button. The HTML isn't ideal but it is what I have to work with.

```
var name = $(this).closest('.text-long').find('.intro-text h4').text();
```

This should find the nearest `<h4>` inner text and store it in the var `name`. However on certain button clicks it's storing a mishmash of text. For example, this is my HTML:

```
<div class="text-long">
  <div class="intro-text">
    <h4>29 Melton Road</h4>
    <div>
      <p>
        <button>click me to save</button>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="button-slot"><a href="#" class="button">View property</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-long">
    <div class="intro-text">
      <h4>32 York Road</h4>
      <div>
        <p>
          <button>click me to save</button>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="button-slot"><a href="#" class="button">View property</a></div>
    </div>
```

When I click the first button it will return `name` as `29 Melton Road32 York Road`, an obvious mish-mash of the two `<h4>`'s which is incorrect.

You can see this in the JSFiddle by checking the console log.

## https://jsfiddle.net/bzd617jf/2/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You have mismatched closing `div`s. The top `<div class="text-long">` doesn't have a closing `</div>` so it actually contains the next `text-long` div too. Fix your tag pairs and try again. They should be:

```
<div class="text-long">
  <div class="intro-text">
    <h4>29 Melton Road</h4>
    <div>
      <p>
        <button>click me to save</button>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="button-slot"><a href="#" class="button">View property</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="text-long">
  <div class="intro-text">
    <h4>32 York Road</h4>
    <div>
      <p>
        <button>click me to save</button>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="button-slot"><a href="#" class="button">View property</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You beat me to it. Indeed he is missing a closing `</div>` tag

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because your HTML is malformed. The `.text-long` elements are not closed correctly so the next `.text-long` element is actually a child of the former. This is why clicking the first button returns the text of the `h4` elements in the parent and all its children.

To fix this you should ideally correct your HTML. If you are unable to do this you can amend the jQuery to select only the first `.intro-text` element it finds withing the container:

```
$('body').on('click', '.icon.heart button', function(e) {
    var name = $(this).closest('.text-long').find('.intro-text h4').first().text();
    console.log(name);
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/bzd617jf/3/)

This is what the version with corrected HTML should look like:

```
<div class="text-long">
    <div class="intro-text">
        <h4>29 Melton Road</h4>
        <div class="col-xs-6 bottom-buffer camera-slot">
            <p class="icon heart">
                <button>click me to save</button>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="button-slot"><a href="http://localhost:8888/test-properties/properties/29-melton-road/" class="button base-color full">View property</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="text-long">
    <div class="intro-text">
        <h4>32 York Road</h4>
        <div class="col-xs-6 bottom-buffer camera-slot">
            <p class="icon heart">
                <button>click me to save</button>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="button-slot"><a href="http://localhost:8888/test-properties/properties/32-york-road/" class="button base-color full">View property</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$('body').on('click', '.icon.heart button', function(e) {
    var name = $(this).closest('.text-long').find('.intro-text h4').text();
    console.log(name);
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/bzd617jf/4/)

Answer (score 0):

here is what you need to change in Jquery code

```
   //localStorage.clear();   
   $('body').on('click', '.icon.heart button', function(e) {
     var name = $(this).parents('.text-long:first').find('.intro-text:first h4').text();
      console.log(name);
   });
```

[Updated Jsfiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/bzd617jf/5/)